# New Azure Website, uploaded content via FTP, and get "nothing here yet" message, very puzzled

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have uploaded Azure Websites numerous times before, so this issue is really puzzling me. I have a MVC3 .NET4.5 Web application which is not precompiled.

I have created a new "Basic" , "Small" Azure website.

I have copied up my web application, using BeyondCompare, via FTP. Always worked well.

Now when I try to run the site, I get:

```
This web site has been successfully created

There's nothing here yet, but Microsoft Azure makes it simple to publish content with GIT, FTP or 
your favorite development tool such as Visual Studio, Visual Studio Online or WebMatrix
```

I tried to access a url like:

```
http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/home/index
```

But all I get is:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Which looks like a 404 error. But I can see all the files via BeyondCompare and they are identical to the ones on the Dev server which works fine.

There is no "hostingstart.html" file which I now understand does not get created when one first creates a new site.

I am either doing something really silly or there is something weird going on.

Some enlightenment would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer. So for the benefit of all. The deployment path should be

```
ftp://......ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot
```

not

```
ftp://......ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
```

as I was accidentally doing.

Hope it helps someone